# Multilple Models In XNA 3.1

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, 3d-modelling, xna-3.0

I have XNA 3.1, how do I load multiple models in xna 3.1 for rendering either from array or button click or switches anything? I just need to load multiple 3d models to render.

This is the link

[LINK](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/15459/80961.aspx)

Where I get code, but this code is in 4.0

```
Model[ ] modelArray;

protected override void LoadContent() 
{
   modelArray = new Model[3];
   modelArray[0] = Content.Load<Model>("model1");
   modelArray[1] = Content.Load<Model>("model2");
   modelArray[2] = Content.Load<Model>("model3");
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime time)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.LightBlue);
    foreach (Model m in modelArray) 
    {
       foreach (BasicEffect be in m.Effects) 
       {
          be.World = YOURWORLDMATRIX;
          be.View = YOURVIEWMATRIX;
          be.Projection = YOURPROJECTIONMATRIX;
       }
       m.Draw();
    }
    base.Draw(time);
}
```

Errors occur in this line, they show me this error:

```
ERROR1:'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model' does not contain a definition for    
   'effects' and no extension method 'effects' accepting a first argument of type  
         'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model' could be found (are you missing a 
       using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and also same error in Draw:

```
  'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model' does not contain a definition for 'draw' 
       and no 
    extension method 'draw' accepting a first argument of type 
    'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model' could be found (are you missing a using 
      directive or an assembly reference?)
```

in these lines

```
m.Effects
m.Draw();
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The drawing procedure is different, try this:

```
foreach (Model m in modelArray) 
{
   foreach (ModelMesh mesh in m.Meshes)
   {
       foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
       {
          be.World = YOURWORLDMATRIX;
          be.View = YOURVIEWMATRIX;
          be.Projection = YOURPROJECTIONMATRIX;
       }
       mesh.Draw();
   }
}
```

Reference [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx).

PS: As convention, do not use uppercase for your varables.